# How to create an integration test with citrus for quarkus application?

Tags: quarkus, junit5, citrus-framework

I've been trying to integrate citrus framework with my quarkus application for hours now without success. All I need is to start a citrus integration test that has @QuarkusTest annotation on it. My test framework is Junit5. How to define the endpoints without using spring?

I added @CitursSupport to the test class and @CitrusTest to the method, which seems to start Citrus, but citrus injection annotations (@CitrusEndpoint, @CitrusFramework, @CitrusResource) don't work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or how to improve the quality of your question. Then edit your question to include your full source code and error message even stacktrace you have as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can be compiled and tested by others. Included sources [should be in text format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5043481), not an image.